# nzTour start function promise resolved too soon?

Tags: javascript

The docs for the nzTour library say the start function should return a promise that gets resolved/rejected when the tour is complete/aborted. For me, it looks like it gets resolved immediately - here's my code, and the logging line shows right after a call to start - the first tour step is still shown.

```
                var run = function (tour) {
                        if (running) {
                            return $q.when();
                        }
                        running = true;
                        return nzTour.start(tour)['finally'](function () {
                            logger.log('nztour start finished');
                            running = false;
                        });
                    };
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a problem with the documentation, or maybe with the library itself?

Comment: Not sure why that isn't working for me, but I found a work-around - the onComplete callback seems to work as expected.

Comment: Had to also handle onClose in case the tour was aborted...